# Fetch the process instances by passing the multiple business key[processBusinessKey] values

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have one process which has task and form fields. And I have one field "location" which I am considering as business key.  For example, I have 2 locations as: India and UK. I want to fetch the process instances of these two locations. Means I need to pass the multiple business key values. Is it possible to pass the multiple business key values and fetch the process instances of these 2 business key values [multiple business key values]?

Thanks & Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box functionality for this. but you can always query `process instances` based on variable values. e.g. create a service which takes multiple keys as argument and query them separately with `runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().variableValueLike("location", "yourKey").list();` this will return all process instances with having `location` as `yourKey` entered.

Answer (score 0):

An Activiti process instance can only have a single associated Business key. However you can retrieve a list of instaces based on a list of buisiness keys and other properties by using a process instance query.